# Issue with scrollview in Fragment layout

Tags: java, android

`ScrollView` is not scrolling when having multiple `linearLayouts` in it. 
   `ScrollView` is also inside a `linearLayout`. Below is my `fragment.xml` code

I am using `youtubePlayer` above the screen and under this using buttons to 
   play other videos in scroll view.

I have searched and change accordingly but not solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearTitle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ScrollView

            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4.0">


                          <My ImageButtons>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4.0">


                   <My ImageButtons>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4.0">


                    <My ImageButtons>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4.0">

                  <My ImageButtons>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4.0">


                   <My ImageButtons>

                </LinearLayout>



                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Scroll view only supports one direct child.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259607/if-scrollview-only-supports-one-direct-child-how-am-i-supposed-to-make-a-whole

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to put `ScrollView` inside `LinearLayout` (since this `LinearLayout` doesn't have any element other than `ScrollView`). Second, you should put your `ScrollView` to the bottom of your `FrameLayout`.

Refer below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ScrollView

        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/youtube_frame">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4.0">


                <My ImageButtons>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4.0">


                <My ImageButtons>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4.0">


                <My ImageButtons>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4.0">

                <My ImageButtons>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4.0">


                <My ImageButtons>

            </LinearLayout>


            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks dear very much for your help

Comment: If it helped, then I believe you can mark it as accepted answer. Anyways, always happy to help. Happy Coding :)